# error while creating new table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Im creating a table in SQL but Im getting the error...

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' pub_name VARCHAR, pub_city VARCHAR, country ' at line 2

CREATE TABLE  publisher(  
'pub_id'      varchar(8),  
'pub_name'        varchar(50),  
'pub_city'        varchar(25),  
'country'         varchar(25),  
'country_office'  varchar(25)  
'no_of_branch'    int(3),  
'estd'           date);
```

Comment: The error message and the query do not match.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b95e1)   [Fiddle2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfa89) missed the comma after country_office field

Comment: We need to understand usage of Backticks in the creation of Tables.Instead of using the single quotes you should follow to use the backticks. Backticks are used to avoid the conflicts between the [mysql reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a `,` after the 'country_office' line.

Btw, you should use reverse quotes : ` around each column name and not simple one !

```
CREATE TABLE publisher (  
`pub_id`          varchar(8),
`pub_name`        varchar(50),
`pub_city`        varchar(25),
`country`         varchar(25),
`country_office`  varchar(25),  <-
`no_of_branch`    int(3),
`estd`            date );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE publisher
(  
`pub_id` varchar(8),  
`pub_name` varchar(50),  
`pub_city` varchar(25),  
`country` varchar(25),  
`country_office` varchar(25),  --The problem is here, You are missing a comma
`no_of_branch` int(3),
`estd` date
);
```

Also you should use **`** instead of **'**

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfa89)**

Thank for the **Fiddle [The Unlucky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1353243/the-unlucky)**

Comment: [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfa89) check this fiddle ....

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE  publisher(pub_id varchar(8), pub_name varchar(50),  
pub_city varchar(25), country varchar(25), country_office varchar(25) , no_of_branch  int(3), estd date);
```